# RealmProxy Classes are not generating in Realm 5.0.0

Tags: android, realm, parceler

I am using realm with parceler. As per documentation I have to add following annotation :

```
@org.parceler.Parcel(implementations =  {SomeClassRealmProxy.class},value = org.parceler.Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,analyze = {SomeClass.class})
```

But after updating realm to version 5.0.0 SomeClassRealmProxy class has not been generated.

Comment: I think it's called something much longer. Like `your_package_and_stuff_SomeClassRealmProxy.class`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you please explain more?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i am facing same issue.

Comment: @Aks4125 it has a different name. It's not called `SomeClassRealmProxy` anymore, it has the full package name as a prefix with `_`s as separators.

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @EpicPandaForce. I am able to resolve this error by importing proxy classes as following way.

```
import io.realm.com_example_test_SomeClassRealmProxy;
```

> You don't need to import like this. It will be automatically generated after successful build. It's your call.

Here, `com.example.test` is the package name and `SomeClass` class is your model class which extends `RealmObject`.

So, finally your proxy name would be

```
@Parcel(implementations = {com_example_test_SomeClassRealmProxy.class},
    value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
    analyze = {SomeClass.class})
```

`com_example_test_model_SomeClassRealmProxy.class // if SomeClass.class is inside model package`

Clean -> Rebuild. There you go.